# Alternative to CURRENT_ROLE() to get the USER roles, not the CURRENT_USER roles? (For use in triggers w/ definer)

Tags: mysql

In a trigger I want to check what roles are active for the USER(), not the CURRENT_USER(). 
(Recognizing, that CURRENT_USER() returns the DEFINER for the trigger).

Is there any sort of USER_ROLE() or way to query some other tables for this information?

E.g., If I have this trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`r_nddb_admin`@`localhost` TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON `test_table`
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN  

INSERT INTO temp (v_user, v_current_user, v_current_role) VALUES (USER(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE());

END"
```

The CURRENT_ROLE that's inserted is NONE because the definer account doesn't have any roles set.

```
User@localhost |    r_nddb_admin@%  |  NONE
```

However, I'd like to check what roles the executor of the trigger [USER()] has active.

Answer (score 0):

They just updated documentation for version 8.0.19 (which is not yet released).

It looks like this will be possible by examining the [information_schema.enabled_roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enabled-roles-table.html) table, which in a bizarre coincidence, was just added to the 8.0.19 documentation (which isn't released yet).

I guess I'll just wait...